# Best way to Highlight Code with Easybook

Tags: php, symfony, php-easybook

I have been using Easybook quite a while recently and I am experiencing issues when wanting to highlight code with geshi using any of the available styles: fences and/or github.

I have just came across the Symfony documentation like code highlighting and would love to intergrate this with my portable files. Below is an image:

[image]

How possible is it to create this kind of styling with the option of turning the line numbering on?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that all I needed to do was to add spaced before I could add my code like we do here in StackOverflow so my problem is solved.